# How do I get the link of the user-provided image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a little website where users will be able to paste images into it. I want to get the link for that pasted image. What I get right now is:

```
data:image/png;base64,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
```

And like 500 000 more characters.

This is the code I'm using too get the pasted image:

```
  document.getElementById('pasteArea').onpaste = function (event) {
  var items = (event.clipboardData  || event.originalEvent.clipboardData).items;
  console.log(JSON.stringify(items)); // will give you the mime types
  // find pasted image among pasted items
  var blob = null;
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].type.indexOf("image") === 0) {
      blob = items[i].getAsFile();
    }
  }
  // load image if there is a pasted image
  if (blob !== null) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event) {
      console.log(event.target.result); // data url!
      document.getElementById("pastedImage").src = event.target.result;
        console.log(event.target.result);
        alert(event.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
  }
    }
```

Then i display it using `<div class="absoluteText square"> <img id="pastedImage"/> </div>`

I want to be able to easily refer to this image somehow. For example open in in another tab.
So how would I go about getting a normal link to that image, preferably user-side?

Comment: if you're not uploading your image to a server somewhere then it won't have a link that you can use. Do you simply need the link to display the image? If so you can use the base64 encoded image to display it

Comment: No, I want to be able to reverse search it using google. So you're saying I would need to host it on a server first?

Comment: When the user pastes an image, all you get is its pixels.
If you want to avoid an upload, maybe you could give the user an option to explicitly paste an URL instead of an image, but that is it.
If all you have is its pixels, then you would need to upload the image somewhere so that a link can be created for it.

Answer (score 0):

convert file to blob url. Below code will get all multiple files into array and can be stored in the backend.

```
var filesArray = new Array();
var file = document.getElementById('XYZ').files[0];
    if(file){
        var reader = new FileReader(); 
        reader.onloadend = function(e) {
            filesArray.push(e.target.result);
        };  
        reader.readAsDataURL(file); 
    }
```

Below code will fetch the filename (php)

```
foreach($filesArray as $key => $value){
   $data = explode(',',$value);
   $typeFile = explode('/', $data[0]);
   $extension = explode(';', $typeFile[1]);
   $fileName = base64_decode($data[1]);
}
```

Save the filename in the database